# implementation to database/sql.Scanner interface

Tags: sql, go

How to make an implementation to `database/sql.Scanner` interface?

In this query there are 3 fields in the SELECT clause:

- `id` smallint unsigned
- `is_suspended` tinyint unsigned
- `name` varchar

In `database/sql` the data types in the 3 columns are:

- `int64`
- `int64`
- `[]uint8`

This works with `[]interface{}`, but want to implement each column type directly into `database/sql.Scanner` interface

```
cols    := make([]interface{}, 3)
ptr     := make([]interface{}, 3)

for i, _ := range cols {
    ptr[i] = &cols[i]
}

if err := rows.Scan(ptr...); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("err:", err)
}

// pair column data with column name
res := map[string]any
for i, name := range res_cols {
    res[name] = *ptr[i].(*any)
    
    fmt.Printf("Type: %T %s\n", res[name], name)
}
```

What I try to do, but can't really make it work

Types

```
type Type_int int

func (t *Type_int) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    switch value := value.(type) {
    case int64:
        *t = Type_int(value)
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("Invalid database type: %T %v", value, value)
    }
    return nil
}

type Type_string string

func (t *Type_string) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    switch value := value.(type) {
    case []uint8:
        *t = Type_string(value)
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("Invalid database type: %T %v", value, value)
    }
    return nil
}
```

code

```
ptr     := make([]interface{}, 3)

cols    := []interface{}{
    Type_int,
    Type_int,
    Type_string,
}

for i, _ := range cols {
    ptr[i] = &cols[i]
}

if err := rows.Scan(ptr...); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("err:", err)
}

// pair column data with column name
res := map[string]any
for i, name := range res_cols {
    res[name] = *ptr[i].(*any)
    
    fmt.Printf("Type: %T %s\n", res[name], name)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `ptr` with pointers to values of the given types.

```
var c1 Type_int
var c2 Type_int
var c3 Type_string
ptr := []any{&c1, &c2, &c3}
if err := rows.Scan(ptr...); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("err:", err)
}
```

The `ptr` slice does not provide any value in the snippet above. The code can be simplified to:

```
var c1 Type_int
var c2 Type_int
var c3 Type_string
if err := rows.Scan(&c1, &c2, &c3); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("err:", err)
}
```

Comment: When running the last version of your code: `interface conversion: interface {} is *Type_int, not *interface {}`

Comment: But need the `map` because the models are not static and are created runtime

Comment: (1) The last version of the code follows [this pattern in the sql package](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4cd201b14b6216e72ffa175747c20d1191e5eb57/src/database/sql/sql_test.go#L277). Is that error message at compile time or runtime?  (2) I have no idea why a map is relevant given that your question does not mention maps.  Perhaps you can clarify that in an edit to the question.

Comment: The error is at runtime.. Have added more code to show how the data is processed after `Scan`

Comment: After `Scan` I pair the column data with column name in a map

Comment: Your program panics on `res[name] = *ptr[i].(*any)`, something that's not in my answer.  The values in `ptr` have types `*Type_int` and `*Type_string`, not `*any`.  The panic is expected.

Comment: How to pair the column name and column data without panic? :)

Comment: I found out :) thanks.. :)